# Select stock status in category->getProductCollection

Tags: stock, product-collection

I am trying to get the stock status of all products within a particular category. My current code is below but `getIsInStock` is not part of the default collection. How can i get this value in the same way as `->addAttributeToSelect('product_type')`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_cat_id)->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('product_type');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    if( $product->getIsInStock() ) { 
        print $product->getProductType().' is in stock';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_cat_id)->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('product_type');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
  $prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/prodcut')->load($product->getId());
  if( $prod->getIsInStock() ) { 
    print $prod->getProductType().' is in stock';
 }
}
```

why we are crating a new object of catalog because when we fetch the products form the category then we got limited attributes so we need to load product again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_cat_id);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('product_type');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getIs_in_stock();
    if($stock == 1 && $product->isAvailable() == 1)
        print $product->getProductType().' is in stock';
}
?>
```